# When the bottom of a div reaches the bottom of the page

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make my sidebar (its height is more than 100%) to be fixed when the its bottom reaches the bottom of the page.

The css:

```
#sidebar { background: red; height: auto; padding: 30px; }
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar"> ... </div>
```

I think jQuery is the solution, but I don't know how to make this happen.

Thanks!

Comment: if height is more then 100%, how can you reach bottom when you are already at the bottom?

Comment: I mean when the bottom of the sidebar it's visible at the bottom of the window, not document. Not sure if you understand me..

Comment: so you want to change sidebar `display:fixed` when you scroll down to the bottom of the page? I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Try to be more specific and please provide us with some more code or maybe a fiddle so you can actually get some sort of solution for your problem

Answer (score 1):

You take for example the html height and subtract the windows height.

Written in jQuery:

```
var bottomScroll = $('html').height() - $(window).height();
```

This will give you the scroll value, when there is no more left to scroll. From that value you can subtract the margin/bottom/height or some other way you are positioning your sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Set the max height to 100% and set its parent (possibly html,body) to height:100%;

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
}
#sidebar{
    max-height:100%;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pg5rp/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand your question, but if you want to set position:fixed to the #sidebar when reached the bottom(I don't know the logic behind that), this script should do the trick:

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $("#sidebar").css({
            "position": "fixed",
        });
        alert("the sidebar is fixed!");
    }
  });  
});
```

Live example - http://jsfiddle.net/Kg7cz/1/